# how can i import a project to cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I have my cakephp in this path of my computer C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp and everything work fine, i made a few exercises and examples to know and learn more of cakephp and that projects and examples works fine too but her is the question, now i have other project with whole files how comes cakephp (app,lib,plugin,vendors etc..) this files running fine but i need to see his functionality because i need to modified or add some features (this is my goal) but i dont know how import or modified the route.php file in cakephp for use this whole project in my localhost.

One idea through my mind is take every single model,ctp file component etc.. and copy and paste from this new project to my cakephp but i dont have a very good feel about this idea, if some one could help me i'm going to be very grateful and thanks

Comment: From your question, I am getting that you want to maintain an existing CakePHP project. Why don't you take a backup of the original working project, make a copy of it (with a different name in your XAMPP) and work on it? Once satisfied, you can present the new copy as the final project. You may have to change some settings to make the copied project work.

Comment: oww ok , but i'm a little confused can i take this new project and overwrite (app,lib,plugins etc..) from my existing cakephp with this same file but from my new project? and that's how can work with other project.? sorry maybe this kind of question are dummy and thanks you very much for answer :D

Comment: I am not getting why you are so bent on combining these two projects. If you can get one project to work on XAMPP, why not just take a backup, then edit it as per the requirements. What is stopping you from doing as I suggested in the earlier comment? Is the original project not working? Is there some configuration issue? Can you connect to database?

Comment: thanks, i make a copy of my cake and replace with this new one project like you said and everything works fine thanks for you answer, i'm working to solve this another problem,
"
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) requires a database connection
Error: Confirm you have created the file : app\Config\database.php."

this happens when i try to login in this project but this is other issue, thanks again.

Tono;

Comment: You're welcome. I have added the solution as an answer so that you can mark this question as having an accepted answer (to help others, to say thanks) by clicking the tick-mark just left to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: In general whenever you face errors, (1) read the error message and understand what it says and do some debugging. (2) If does not work, search for the exact error message, see the solutions on Internet, tweak your code and see if it works. (3) If not, take help from a willing colleague or search on StackOverflow for similar errors. (4) If not then, ask a well-written question and let us help each other.

Comment: Try this way of programming for your SQLSTATE error. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I am getting that you want to maintain an existing CakePHP project.

Why don't you take a backup of the original working project, make a copy of it (with a different name in your XAMPP) and work on it? Once satisfied, you can present the new copy as the final project. You may have to change some settings to make the copied project work.

In other words, if you can get one project to work on XAMPP, why not just take a backup, then edit it as per the requirements.

Comment: thanks again , your answer and patients make my problem have a solution in time, thanks again and keep going like this ;)

Comment: @Tonoid Your kind words made my day! I will keep going like this :)